# Assign values to a matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, variable-assignment

I have wrote this piece of code and need to generate a matrix and save it. But, when assigning the matrix values, it says "KeyError: 0"!! Anybody has an idea what is the reason? thanks

```
import numpy as np
l=5; x=0; z=5; y=np.arange(0,5,0.5)
positions = { (i,j):0 for i in range(l) for j in range(2)}
for i in range(l):
    positions[i][0]=x
    positions[i][1]=y[i]
    positions[i][2]=z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the shape of matrix you need but assuming something like:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

then code:

```
import numpy as np
l=5; x=0; z=5; y=np.arange(0,5,0.5)

positions = [[0 for j in range(3)] for i in range(l)]

print(positions)

for i in range(l):
    positions[i][0]=x
    positions[i][1]=y[i]
    positions[i][2]=z
```

Answer (score 0):

It's how you structured your keys, it should be a `tuple` instead of something `array` like

```
import numpy as np
l=5; x=0; z=5; y=np.arange(0,5,0.5)
positions = { (i,j):0 for i in range(l) for j in range(2)}
for i in range(l):
    positions[(i, 0)] = x
    positions[(i, 1)] = y[i]
    positions[(i, 2)] = z
```